# Promise.all() each promise response

Tags: javascript, promise, ionic3

I need to call ascync operations in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < message.destinatarios.length; i++) {
  messageList.push(this.sms.send(destinatario.numero_celular, string));
 // this will take a litle time to be executed
}

// Here I need something to be fired each time one of the promises in messageList is resolved

Promise.all(messageList)
  .then(res => {
     //that is executed when all the promises have been resolved 
  })
  .catch(err => {
     // that is executed when some of then fail
  });
```

Then for each response I need to increment a counter like this

```
console.log("processing " + counter++ + " of " + messageList.length);
```

How would I do that in correct way since I need to wait for all promises to be fufilled until moving to the next step?

Comment: Why increment a counter if you have an index? Promise.all will give you all of the results in the order you sent them.

Comment: Does `this.sms.send()` return a promise?

Comment: Yes, this.sms.send returns a promise @Ozan

Comment: I edited it @Xufox, but thats is not the real code just giving an example

Comment: @KevinB, The counter has the pourpose to be incremented when the promise is resolved. The index is for something else

Comment: @WelderMarcos Right, but if you're using promise.all, you wouldn't need to count them as they're being resolved. You would already have a callback that gets called when they're all done with all of the results.

Comment: @KevinB, counting them as they are finished could still be needed, apart from waiting them all with `Promise.all()`. Imagine if you needed to show a `x of y works have been completed` message to the user for example.

Comment: @KevinB Some external process could be dependent on this counter, e.g. it should run only if more than half of that promises are resolved. I don't know...

Comment: exactly @Ozan...

Comment: A counter like what you already have should be fine for that, assuming you fix the typo and declare the counter at a location where it won't be redeclared with each iteration. **But you didn't include that part of your code.**

Comment: The index is for the iteration of the message.destinatarios array. Each time the loop executes that iteration will send an ascyncronous function that will execute for some time. I want to increment the counter just after that ascyncronous function is resolved. **got it ?** @KevinB

Comment: @WelderMarcos Yes, does what you have not already do that? **we still can't see what you currently have** All you've shown us is a random console.log

Comment: I'll Edit to clarify @KevinB

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341331/es6-promise-all-progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a `resolveCallback` to each promise.
Then, use `Promise.all()` to wait for all your promises to do whatever work that needs to wait for all of them to finish.

```
let counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < message.destinatarios.length; i++) {
  const prom = this.sms.send(destinatario.numero_celular, string);
  messageList.push(prom);
  prom.then(() => {
    //your logic for whatever you want to do for every time a promise is resolved
    console.log("processing " + ++counter + " of " + messageList.length); 
  })
}
Promise.all(messageList)
```

Comment: Seems the most atractive way to solve it, but will the response in each promise affect the Promise.all response?

Comment: @WelderMarcos, No.

Answer (score -1):

Promise.all  runs nested promises in parallel. You can't use counter AFAIK. At least without changing counter as a side-effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining @Alex