# How to abort a batch of async fetch requests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I currently have a list of coordinates, which i use to fetch nearby hikes. Lets say I update my list state to new coordinates, but the fetch requests for the previous coordinates were not complete-- How can i cancel all the fetch requests made for the previous coordinates and only call new fetch requests based on the new coordinates?

I tried implementing `AbortController` but its probably not working as it's not cancelling a "batch" of fetch requests, but only single fetch request. My code is below:

```
  let abortController = new AbortController();
  const getNearbyHikes = async (coordinates) => {
    abortController.abort();
    abortController = new AbortController();
    for (const coord of coordinates) {
      if (coord) {
        try {
          const { lat, lng } = cord.coordinates
          const response = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:5000/category/' + lat + "/" + lng + '/' + searchCategory,
            {signal: abortController.signal}
          )
          const result = await response.json();
          setHikes((prevState) => [...prevState, ...result.businesses])
        } catch (error) {
          if(error.name === 'AbortError'){
            return;
          }
          throw error
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

Also , I want to update my UI with the hikes as I get them so it doesnt seem like my web app is really slow so I avoid using `Promise.all`. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `const response = await` your waiting, not batching so there will only ever be one to cancel.  Have a look at using `Promise.all` to batch

Comment: This looks like it's basically a typo. You're providing the signal as the second argument, but that's not what `fetch` expects, it expects an **object** with a `signal` property  (and optionally others). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#syntax

Comment: @Keith Yea thats what i assumed, but i really want to avoid using `Promise.all` as I dont want my user to wait for all the data to load before its displayed.  Would `Promise.all` still be a good solution or is there another suggestion. Thank you!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I didnt catch that although it doesnt change my outcome.

Comment: @benwl - That suggests a problem in code that isn't shown, since that will work.

Comment: @benwl  Yes, if using `Promise.all` your still able to update your display.  You basically attach to the `thenable`, .. It's kind of the technique I used for creating a `Promise.all` with a progress callback ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341331/es6-promise-all-progress

Answer (score 5):

The main problem with the cancellation is that you're providing the signal to `fetch` incorrectly. You're providing the signal as a second argument, but `fetch` expects an "init" object there with a `signal` property on it.

As @Keith points out, though, your current code is making one call at a time. That will work, but you probably would benefit from doing the calls in parallel.

Something like this:

```
const getOneResult = async ({ lat, lng }, signal) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:5000/category/" +
                lat +
                "/" +
                lng +
                "/" +
                searchCategory, // *** Where does this come from?
            { signal }
        );
        if (signal && signal.aborted) {
            throw new DOMException("Request cancelled", "AbortError");
        }
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "AbortError") {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
const getNearbyHikes = async (coordinates, signal) => {
    controller.abort();
    controller = new AbortController();
    const results = await Promise.all(
        coordinates.map((coord) => getOneResult(coord.coordinates, signal))
    );
    if (signal && signal.aborted) {
        return;
    }
    const businesses = [];
    for (const result of results) {
        businesses.push(...result.businesses);
    }
    setHikes((prevState) => [...prevState, ...businesses]);
};
```

Finally, I would have the caller supply the signal rather than using a global one for all calls to `getHikes`:

```
const getOneResult = async ({ lat, lng }, signal) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:5000/category/" +
                lat +
                "/" +
                lng +
                "/" +
                searchCategory, // *** Where does this come from?
            { signal }
        );
        if (signal && signal.aborted) {
            throw new DOMException("Request cancelled", "AbortError");
        }
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "AbortError") {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
let controller = new AbortController();
const getNearbyHikes = async (coordinates) => {
    controller.abort();
    controller = new AbortController();
    const results = await Promise.all(
        coordinates.map((coord) => getOneResult(coord.coordinates, signal))
    );
    if (signal && signal.aborted) {
        return;
    }
    const businesses = [];
    for (const result of results) {
        businesses.push(...result.businesses);
    }
    setHikes((prevState) => [...prevState, ...businesses]);
};
```

then the caller controls aborting the request. But the former may be fine for your use case.

---

Side note: You'll see I've added a check for `response.ok` in there. Your code was assuming that since the `fetch` promise was fulfilled, the HTTP call worked, but unfortunately that's a footgun in the `fetch` API: it only rejects its promise on *network* failure, not HTTP failure. You have to check for the latter explicitly.

Comment: Gah, I accidentally dropped your handling of `AbortError`, **and** you probably need at least one explicit check on `signal.aborted` (in case the `fetch` was already complete).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanations and suggestions. Im pretty new and i just need some time to digest what you said.  But to clarify something simpler for now, how come i should do `...results.map(({businesses}) => businesses)` instead and could you explain for about what you mean about further processing?

Comment: @benwl - That part of the answer was basically wrong I think, your original code expected an array of businesses on each result and pushed them all to `setHikes` individually, but that code would have tried to pass an array of arrays. I've updated the answer to fix the issues I mentioned above and to also handle `businesses` correctly (I think).