# React Promise.all().then() called before each setState from promise.then() is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to call 200 remote resources to show in my table, with a progress bar showing the amount of calls remaining.

Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341331/es6-promise-all-progress) on how to use `Fetch()` with `Promise.all()` to call `setState()` with the new data.

My problem lies in the `.then()` for each promise, which computes some logic, and then calls `setState()` to update the data.

My progress bar uses `Object.keys(data).length` to show the progress.

After the `Promise.all()` triggers the 'done' state, removing the progess bar, the promises themself are still calling there `then()` which causes the progress bar to be hidden before it shows the full amount of promises resolved.

What is the correct way of dealing with this?

---

Demo, which uses `setTimeout()` to mimic the expensive logic.

Issue is that the `Promise.all.then: 20` should become **after** `Render 20`.

```
Render 0
...
Render 12
Promise.all.then:  20       # I need this to log after each Render
Render 13
...
Render 19
Render 20
```

To make the demo show the issue the progress bar is removed (turned red) before it's completely full.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [done, setDone] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
      
    const demoData = Array.from(Array(20).keys());
    const demoResolver = (x) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(x), Math.random() * 1250))
    
    const loadData = () => {
        
        const promises = demoData.map(c => demoResolver(c));
          
        promises.forEach(promise => {
            promise
                .then(r => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setData(p => ({ ...p, [r]: r }));
                    }, 500);
                })
        });
         
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(r => {
                console.log('Promise.all.then: ', r.length)
                setDone(true);
            })
    }
    
    console.log('Render', Object.keys(data).length);
  
    const progressBarIsShownDebugColor = (done)
      ? 'is-danger'
      : 'is-info';
    
    return (
        <section className='section'>
            <h1 className='title is-3'>{'Example'}</h1>
            <progress 
                max={demoData.length}
                value={Object.keys(data).length} 
                className={'progress my-3 ' + progressBarIsShownDebugColor}
            />
            <button onClick={loadData}>Start</button>
        </section>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 50px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused-- why are you running all the promises twice?

Comment: @MattMorgan Promises only run once, ever. If you call `.then` again *after it's already resolved*, or in this case `.all` on an array of Promises, it resolves immediately. In this specifc case, since it's not awaited, an additional `.then` is added to each Promise, which is queued up for once it resolves.

Comment: What is the point of the `setTimeout` with the 500ms delay?!

Answer (score 1):

The issue shown in the code above is that you have an additional 500ms async delay after getting the data before setting the state. In the real code, it sounds similar that there is extra processing (probably sync) causing the `setData`s to be called after the `.all`.

The best thing to do is to make `done` be a computed property instead of a separate state, since at that point you don't need to rely on state setting races and `Object.keys(data).length` is cheap enough where it won't decrease performance (plus you're using it in other areas, if it became a concern you could cache it in a variable).

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const done = Object.keys(data).length === 20; // 200 in the real code
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const done = Object.keys(data).length === 20; // 200 in the real code
      
    const demoData = Array.from(Array(20).keys());
    const demoResolver = (x) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(x), Math.random() * 1250))
    
    const loadData = () => {
        
        const promises = demoData.map(c => demoResolver(c));
          
        promises.forEach(promise => {
            promise
                .then(r => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setData(p => ({ ...p, [r]: r }));
                    }, 500);
                })
        });
    }
    
    console.log('Render', Object.keys(data).length);
  
    const progressBarIsShownDebugColor = (done)
      ? 'is-danger'
      : 'is-info';
    
    return (
        <section className='section'>
            <h1 className='title is-3'>{'Example'}</h1>
            <progress 
                max={demoData.length}
                value={Object.keys(data).length} 
                className={'progress my-3 ' + progressBarIsShownDebugColor}
            />
            <button onClick={loadData}>Start</button>
        </section>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 50px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a push in the right direction. I'm now using an `useEffect` which checks if `done` needs to be set and then do the logic that first was in the `Promise.all().then`, not sure why I didn't think of that earlier. I'll wait until tomorrow should somebody else come along with a better answer, otherwise I'll accept yours.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that the promises are already resolved when their callbacks are called, meaning that `Promise.all` will always be resolved before the execution of the callback of the last setTimeout.

If you want to keep the delay, I think you should put the `setTimeout` inside the `demoResolver`

```
const demoResolver = (x) => new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(() => { // I guess this is to mock the delay of an api call
    setTimeout(() => {
      setData(p => ({ ...p, [x]: x })); 
      res(x);
    }, 500)
  }, Math.random() * 1250)
})
```

Comment: The 'delay' is just to mimic my ApiCall + logic which takes some time, can't change the `demoResolver` in this demo.

Comment: I can only help you with the code you provided, now you know what the problem is so it is up to you to adapt the solution to a real use case :) But if you have any question you can ask